# Is there any way to make text selectable and add custom actions to context menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have React Native project(with Expo). I'm trying to make my text selectable and add custom actions to context menu. After some googling I found `react-native-selectable-text` library which throws errors when I use `SelectableText` component.

This is my initial code:

```js
class RfcItem extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "RfcItem",
    ...navStyles,
  };

  render() {
    const { RFC, loading } = this.props;

    if (loading) return null;
    const { rfc: c } = RFC.content;
    return (
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
        {/* TODO: Make this text selectable */}
        <Text category="h1" status="primary">
          {RFC.content}
        </Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

This is the code with `react-native-selectable-text`:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import navStyles from "../../styles/navStyles";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  PureComponent,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";

import { graphql } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import Markdown from "react-native-markdown-renderer";
import { instanceOf } from "prop-types";

import mdStyles from "../../styles/md";
import sharedStyles from "../../styles/shared";
import { Layout, Text } from "react-native-ui-kitten";

import SelectableText from "react-native-selectable-text";

class RfcItem extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "RfcItem",
    ...navStyles,
  };

  render() {
    const { RFC, loading } = this.props;

    if (loading) return null;
    const { rfc: c } = RFC.content;
    return (
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
        <SelectableText
          selectable
          multiline
          contextMenuHidden
          scrollEnabled={false}
          editable={false}
          onSelectionChange={event => {
            const {
              nativeEvent: {
                selection: { start, end },
              },
            } = event;
            const str = text.substring(start, end);
            onSelectionChange({ str, start, end });
          }}
          style={{
            color: "#BAB6C8",
          }}
          value={"some text"}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

It throws an error: `Tried to register two views with the same name RCTMultipleTextInputView`

How can I add text selection(with context menu)? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Could you edit it to  the exact code that throws error ?

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan Just added code that throws an error

Comment: Was my answer useful ?

Answer (score 0):

When I look into the react-native-selectable-text library, I can't see `onSelectionChange` props just `onSelection`. Also you have to items to display as you have not added `menuItems` props